# Deleted bootstrap_flash_messages gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, rubygems, message

I've deleted this gem https://github.com/RobinBrouwer/bootstrap_flash_messages by 
`rails destroy bootstrap_flash_messages:locale` and remove from gemfile. When i'm running app

> I18n::InvalidLocaleData in Projects#new
>   can not load translations from my_dir/config/locales/flash.en.yml: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - my_dir/config/locales/flash.en.yml

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

In rails 4.1 issue may be in still running Spring, that cached all locale files on moment of its launch.

To fix it, stop all instances of your app (server, console, etc) and execute from your app directory:

```
spring stop
```

Then try to launch your app again, it should be fixed.

On older versions of Rails ou may be using another application preloader (like Zeus), try to stop it too.

Hope it helps.